# VSS Deprecated Files

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

We are using VSS for version control (changing to another version control system is not an option right now), and are occassionally running into issues where a file has been completely deprecated with its functionality split into other new files.  For historical archival reasons we need to keep those files in the version control sytem.  Is there some way to clearly mark them as deprecated and no longer used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the files?

Deleting does not remove the historical versions - there is a separate command Destroy to do that.